# Quantitative comparison Kalman filter VS Least squares

Tags: least-squares, estimation, kalman-filter

I've been asked to give a quantitative confirmation of the Kalman filter that I develop.

My obvious first idea was to compare the residuals.

$$ \chi = {\lvert\lvert C \hat x - y \rvert\rvert}_2^2 $$

where $\hat x$ is the estimate of the state.

However, now that I think of it, the Kalman filter is obviously giving higher residuals. Due to the fact that least-squares by definition is minimizing this quantity...

I mean qualitatively the filter is performing well on simple simulated cases. But it is hard to tell on the real plant. So I'd like to have some quantitative verification.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you minimize over a single or multiple measurements?

Comment: Over around 80 sensors. It is variable

Comment: Ah, but it is you again Kewin. Btw I found a solution to my other question. I'm just a bit stressed with the deadlines now but plan to post an answer asap :)

Comment: Least Squares is a parametric method while Kalman Filter is Bayesian. So comparing them as strictly you described misses the point. Do you have a simulation?